# Conv neural network to tell standard 52-card deck apart

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I'm using the below keras model to train a neural network to tell 52 game cards 23456789TJQA each with Club, Diamond, Heart and Spade apart.

The model is working quite well but occasionally has problems telling Club and Diamond apart, as they are the most similar (and the difference is quite granular). I was wondering if anybody has some suggestions in what way I can improve the below model?

I've tried different things, like converting everything to black and white, grayscale, smoothing, augmentation etc, but nothing seems to solve that problem.

The pictures are all 15x50 pixels, with 1 channel, so the input shape is (15,50,1)

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: The edge of diamond is almost a line but the edge of club is an arc. So I would suggest to increase height/width of your convolution filter to capture that. Since your picture is 15x50, you might use something like 8x8 or 10x10.

Comment: Would that mean reducing the height/width would be better to capture more granularity? I.e. (2,2) instead of (3,3)?